# how to know what hash function have been used

Tags: hash

I have a hashed password and the plaintext password and i want to know the exact algorithm that's been used. I have the input and the output of the hash/encription algorithm. How would I know what algorithm is used?

Comment: Sometimes a hash identification tool does not work because of pre-hash [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) addition. Adding a random or even a non-random string to the password (or in some cases doing a mathematical operation on the password where that operation is only known to the system developers or owners) before hashing it secures it against against rainbow tables and makes it difficult to even detect what type of hashing algorithm was used apart from the obvious length of the hash. So if you have a salted hash, not really much can be done.

Answer (score 2):

There is only one solution: try all known algorithms on your input until you find your output.

Comment: I know. I was hoping there is a program that would do that for me. Do you know where I can find a list of all known algorithms or a program that will hash smth many times with many algorithms

Comment: You may be able to narrow down the possibilities with [a hash identifier tool](https://code.google.com/p/hash-identifier/).

Comment: I've tried it.That's only linux tool right?I've used it with kali, but hash id don't recognize most of my hashes

Answer (score 2):

I've never really tried to do this, but I've hung around with people who do that all the time. What I gather is that it is a bit of an art.

In some cases you can tell by length. For example SHA1 will produce 20 byte hashes (plus salt). Other schemes will have different outputs.  Also you might find this hashes with separators in them (for things like salts and so on). Different systems for creating passwords have various conventions.

The people behind John the Ripper have [a list of samples](http://openwall.info/wiki/john/sample-hashes), but it isn't very complete. But you should at least be able to use it to eliminate some possibilities.

If you have a large dump of hashes, try testing them with some of the plausible formats using just the top 500 or so most common passwords. ()'123456', "Password1', etc).  Once you break one of the hashes with something like that, you will know what scheme is used.

If you want to get some idea of how the experts do this (often with very tricky hashes) you should read some of the write-ups from the teams who have competed in Korelogic's "[Crack Me If You Can](http://contest.korelogic.com)" competitions.

You might try search or posting to the [john-users mailing list](http://www.openwall.com/lists/john-users/). I have found them extremely helpful in these kinds of things.  There is also an active community of haschat users as well.

But because this is an art, most people will need to know more about your hash (where it came from, what it looks like) before they can give you specific help.

Comment: Well thank you for the answers, they really helped me much, and I'm gratefull, but I won't be able to crack most of my hashes, I'm new to this and I thought it would be easier. If you could help me further or crack some hash for me that will be nice and I'll donate some BTC too.

Comment: $1$0t4.Ht1.$.0a.IHEMtCkcV52rnD6E./ $1$0t4.Ht1.$5QRdGjQ14n2X87BIg5ykr/ 351683ea4e19efe34874b501fdbf9792:9b 85c9b16a1223fd97976dc7c9dfccb1f2:c2 51c2d0c55aca2e9690f0ca2ea0924f998cb6eaf64f6c81e920cad6a66c7a1ead8dbd8f42de73f4ac8952e76b48c430caaf43f51cf1c75b14223401bf

Comment: 00a6f3e6 21ce1c5b8073f555457eff1f84ed9ef4751f2838c35e01112ec2b2c39edebe219fd94c7001f25e6a5c4a44c5c8d7f386bf8194926a2de14db3c8690b2e511b82 200b1ac97ce04b5f34b47ad2b0957bd5a95f6d9359f7c1a6fb3f3e75ae4aef213d55a703ef9d8fc3382e73fe1764ffea735ab5d788db60217812679a1b086b62 *13F84CC62636F799FE455B4B4BD45DB6C02F599B *BE8871D5BA47C6C91924D9AA1690F6B5CFA24140 *6BB4837EB74329105EE4568DDA7DC67ED2CA2AD9 2f2119395b88c55448ca1c8a26022af28b6uMg#@MG 2f2119395b88c55448ca1c8a26022af28b6uMg#@MG 30aec92beed3dd31eb8eebfa81b6ba4cSvUGFThKhY b04ec0ade3d49b4a079f0e207d5e2821

Comment: e2653e33fc8e0879c05eb3a9a11cc0f2 a5efa3fa19a6569b6044c9f82c9388d4 $P$BrJ/Ii4AQBJP4f9aOR5xgDd7BzKNJP1 $P$B0m7P/lXoVzQFLRy06gyPfgSCnWinO/ c3cc8da63bed638717a36ceb599ea9bea5b3d080 2229fbbca24bc9c3561cd06cd03ebbf060a16695 5259f675ee5c92c1ac23ce6744fdab2839230244 7886d05720cc2c59923631ef00804c9d3e3492f4 2d77425afcb566a11fd401c5860046db50d929f6 6f50fa58dfa1c46abcd9d74d3f122477b0c81851 05dcd592d1a1ea4849504076cfb810938d9d0525 7886d05720cc2c59923631ef00804c9d3e3492f4 c1a46a82bed3313c59e31247e4cf5fa6386ee3d6

Comment: 8u2CCrVkl1rtPprKw5InxjZW9qZx9DbqSzM9YbgYyvQ= ETplcrIIlod+oF2qKHMQeGGfobDT3RCt5m8RZF9kJA8= m2KCQz8KfuL6c/3PnEhVojuvowBWhTFpxbAQLB9f8uA= wcFKZ2wECNVP2wtRCKlkebGSRzcfq/2/nCLLuFMY/TY=

Comment: 536d7af2672b036749dff45a6728ad56 8b1dfef6cbb0bb774d3e41d884f6d2dd d69f6e61f3d754eb50a09dd52420e8d4 22c61c2ea91e1d4671cc43577eb3a6eb 0d088a80873c9326f7f875a8cec29e2b

Comment: 2f2119395b88c55448ca1c8a26022af28b6uMg#@MG 2f2119395b88c55448ca1c8a26022af28b6uMg#@MG 30aec92beed3dd31eb8eebfa81b6ba4cSvUGFThKhY

Comment: space is separator. Sorry if that's too much that I want.

Comment: see they are all different types and either I'm not able to find out the type or I find many possible types and I'll need to calculate many rainbow tables for each of them and that would take too long...