# How to identify this hashed text and if it encrypted using a key?

Tags: encryption, hash, decryption

I have 2 hashes which I don't remember which type of encryption I used or if i used a secret key.
can you help me identify these I will just give all details but not paste the whole hash here.

hash1 
start: `qe$weroodjf` end:`ejosfkgowieorjwr`  length: `71 bytes`

hash2 
start: `bHQ4VNwAbe3b` end: `TagEhBhrpZXVPqr6jQ==` length: `152 bytes`

NOTE: there was originally `157 bytes` but it was white space i don't if I pressed accidentally or it was there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine what type of encoding/encryption has been used?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3989/), [How to identify hashes](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/91929/), [how to know what hash function have been used](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/41506).

Answer (score 0):

For the second one, I think you mean 152 characters, not 152 bytes.  The character set looks like base64, and the equals symbols at the end are another tell-tale sign that this is probably base64, as equals symbols are often used for padding in base64.

In base64, each set of 4 characters represents 3 bytes.  You have 150 characters of actual information (again, the last two equals symbols are padding).  This equates to 112.5 bytes of data ( (150/4) * 3).  That equates to 900 bits of data (8*112.5).

That's most likely not a hash, as no standard hashing algorithm produces a 900-bit result.  It's most likely not the result of AES encryption either, as AES produces blocks of 128 bits, and 900 is not a multiple of 128.